# rxjs countdown that triggers method

Tags: javascript, angular, timer, rxjs

I am trying to make a 5 mins countdown that triggers a service method and reloads the 5 mins countdown (basically I am trying to reload some data every 5 mins)

```
  constructor(
    private reloadDataService: ReloadDataService,
    private userService: UserService
    ) {
      this.timer$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
        scan(acc => --acc, 300),
        takeWhile(x => x >= 0),
      );
    }
```

realod method is trigger by a button or every 5 mins

```
  reload() {
    this.lastRefresh = new Date();
    this.reloadDataService.reload()
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUserDetails();
  }
```

I have tried with

```
this.timer$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
            switchMap(() => this.reload()),
            scan(acc => --acc, 300),
            takeWhile(x => x >= 0),
          );
```

but didn't work - how can I trigger the reload method every 5 mins?

Comment: could you not just set the timer to repeat every 5 minutes instead of every 1 second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is by using interval or timer function offered by rxjs.

Here is an example that I created.

```
countDown: Subscription = null;
minutes: number = 5;
counter: number = this.minutes * 60;
triggered: number = 0;
```

start timer function

```
startTimer(): void {
  this.countDown ? this.stopTimer() : null;
  this.countDown = interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
    --this.counter;
    if (!this.counter) {
      this.trigger();
    }
  });
}
```

stop timer function

```
stopTimer(): void {
  if (this.countDown) {
    this.countDown.unsubscribe();
    this.countDown = null;
  }
}
```

trigger function that get executed when countdown finish

```
trigger(): void {
  this.counter = this.minutes * 60;
  this.stopTimer(); // unsubscribe timer
  this.startTimer(); // re subscribe timer
  this.triggered++;
  // your code
}
```

[codesandbox ui example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-parm-6opnf?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

I hope this helps you, let me know if you build another solution.

Best wishes,

Dev.klodian

Answer (score 0):

use the subscribe property of timer,

```
const source = timer(0, 300000);
source.subscribe((_) => this.reload());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It will setup the the interval method and when subscribing to **refreshInterval$** you can call reload method or any operation that you want to repeat.

```
const refreshInterval$: Observable<any> = timer(0, 300000)
  .pipe(
    // Boolean to kill the request if the user closes the component 
    takeWhile(() => this.killTrigger));
refreshInterval$.subscribe(() => {
    // Your code here 
});
```